# SSL Certificate Error in Fabric

Tags: android

We're using `fabric.io` for our `Crash analytics`. While doing a security scan of our Android apk, we got the following error:

> Custom TrustManager is implemented in class io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.mImplements naive certificate check. This TrustManager breaks certificate validation!Referenced in method io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.k->a
>   Please clarify on this issue and expected resolution ETA.

What can be done for this?

Comment: Have you tried the [Frabri.io support forums](https://twittercommunity.com/c/fabric)?

Comment: Hi @user2025085, have you got any solution to this.?

Comment: Is there any solution for this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.
Log shown:

> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Maybe try: `save ssl cert as .cer file` by broswer, then add this `cer file` into
`Android Studio/Setting/Tools/Server Certificates`.

Comment: Hi @javaing tried your solution but still the same issue.

Comment: sad to hear this, but now I change office place, there is no this issue.